# Why isn't there a /usr/include/GL directory on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, bsd, opengl, mesa

I have just recently made the switched for Linux to OpenBSD. So far, I am really liking the philosophy of including the bare minimum needed to run the system, and the emphasis for clean and simple code. However, I face a small problem. I am a programmer, and at the moment I am experimenting with and learning how to use the OpenGL API. Unlike Linux, however, there is no `/usr/include/GL` or `/usr/local/include/GL`. I am using the Intel graphics driver, as shown by `screenfetch` and `dmesg`. How would I install the Mesa/OpenGL API header files?

Comment: Did you install `graphics/freeglut`?

Comment: @uzsolt Yes, but that installed the freeglut headers only, not the complete `GL` header packages.

Comment: And the `mesa` package?

Answer (score 2):

Please read `hier(7)`. Xenocara (OpenBSD's Xorg) sits in `/usr/X11R6`.
It even should have separate partition.

BSD Make tend to use mk-files. Special files in `/usr/share/mk`. Some of then include `/usr/X11R6/share/mk`. You can find `X11BASE` variable there to include it into your Makefile.

PS: Some people suggest `/usr/local/include`. Please note that OpenBSD has very clean distinction between base system and third party software.

`/usr/X11R6` is part of base system. It never goes to `/usr/local`. But ony third party software (vim, kde, python) always goes to `/usr/local/`. 
So:

- `/usr/include`: base system (except Xenocara)
- `/usr/X11R6/include`: base system (Xenocara)
- `/usr/local/include`: third party software.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the headers you may be looking for are located in `/usr/X11R6/include/GL`.  This where `gl.h`, `glx.h` and `glu.h` (and others) live on a vanilla OpenBSD system.

You may use `pkg-config` in your Makefile.  The compiler flags needed for the standard OpenBSD Mesa are given by

```
pkg-config --cflags osmesa
```

(returns `-I/usr/X11R6/include`)

And likewise for GL:

```
pkg-config --cflags gl
```

(returns `-I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/X11R6/include/libdrm`)

See [the `pkg-config(1)`manual](http://man.openbsd.org/pkg-config) .

Answer (score 0):

Try including the headers from `/usr/include`, `/usr/X11R6/include` and `/usr/local/include`.